# Draw new line every time mouse is moved in c++ builder

Tags: c++, drawing, draw, c++builder, c++builder-2010

I have a code I want to load every time I move my mouse cursor; it draws line to direction of mouse and beyond, and every time it the line gets to certain x coordinate, the line reflects. The problem is that now the program only draws line when I click on the PaintBox.
Here is my code so far:

```
void __fastcall TForm2::PaintBox1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
   Form2->Refresh();
   TPoint P;
   ::GetCursorPos( &P );
   P = ScreenToClient( P );
   int XX;
   int YY;
   if (P.x<240) 
   {
      XX=15;
      YY= ((445-P.y)*(XX-P.x)/(240-P.x)+P.y);
   } 
   else if(P.x==240)
   {
      XX=240;YY=-5; 
   }
   else
   { 
      XX=465;
      YY= ((445-P.y)*(XX-P.x)/(240-P.x)+P.y);   
   }
   int delta=2*(445-YY);

   this->Canvas->MoveTo(240, 445);
   this->Canvas->LineTo(XX,YY);
   while(0<YY&&YY<480&&YY!=445)
   {
      XX=abs(480-XX);
      YY-=delta;
      this->Canvas->LineTo(XX,YY);
   }
}
```

Comment: You must not draw in the OnClick handler. Draw in the OnPaint handler. You'll need to remember some state. Use Invalidate to trigger a paint cycle.

Comment: How is it possible to change the handler? When I try to change, it gives error that its not a member of TForm2

Comment: Change what handler? Don't describe errors vaguely. Quote them verbatim.

Comment: I changed `void __fastcall TForm2::PaintBox1Click(TObject *Sender)` to `void __fastcall TForm2::PaintBox1Paint(TObject *Sender)` and it gave error: `[BCC32 Error] Unit2.cpp(22): E2316 '_fastcall TForm2::PaintBox1Paint(TObject *)' is not a member of 'TForm2'`

Comment: You've got a header file right? That declares the type. Got to change it there too.

Comment: Thank you! That surely solved my problem, and now I understand c++ builder much better!

Comment: One more thing that is bit frustrating that the lines drawn flash every time the form refresh, is there way to get show lines continuosly?

Comment: ask that in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to paint in an `OnClick` event handler. That's the wrong place to paint. The only correct place to paint to a VCL paint box is from its `OnPaint` event handler.

You will need to respond to `OnClick` though. Make a note of the location of the click and update any state that you need to maintain. Then call `Invalidate` on the paint box to force a paint cycle.